# Change the size of structure element

Tags: image-processing, julia, mathematical-morphology

I'm doing some tests of morphological operators in Julia. So I would like to apply dilation, erosion, etc. to a given image.
When I use the command `ImageMorphology.dilate()`, I get the dilation of an image with the structuring element a 3-sided square.

I would like to increase my structuring element to a square of size 4 x 4, 5 x 5, 6 x 6 and etc. and I can't do that in Julia.
I've read the documentation and can't find anything like it.
Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: It looks like ImageMorphology.jl does not let you specify the neighbourhood at all.  However, maybe you are able to use the [nonlinear filtering function](https://juliaimages.org/stable/function_reference/#ImageFiltering.MapWindow.mapwindow) from ImageFilters.jl instead, and the neighbourhoods of your choices as the `window` argument? (The problem is I only barely remember my computer vision lectures...)

Comment: @phipsgabler, it's great! You help me a lot! Thanks too much